# tokens and security with stripe api for node.js (stripe-node)

Tags: node.js, security, angular, token, stripe-payments

Sort of a newbie question.  I am looking at using Stripe in an Angular 2 application and plan to implement a server (alongside the one serving the angular pages) with node.js to receive tokens from the angular clients and then call stripe-node functions (which require a secret key) from there.  I wonder what if any validation I need to do on the tokens that I receive there.  Since anyone can see the url of that server, could they create problems with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I 100% understand the question but I think I do :D. As you probably know from your client-side code, before the form is actually submitted you make a request to Stripe's servers which return back a specific token representing that card's data, and stripe hides this before submitting the form. This is why the cards information never has to touch your server and voiding you from the PCI compliance issues that would come with that. So you don't have to validate the token if that is what you mean. After this stripe authorizes (the bank tells them you have enough money) and captures (actually transfers the money) the money from the bank, you are given the token and it guarantees there is money on the card to actually pay you, not sure if that is what you mean by validates. If they cannot pay it will throw an error. In terms of the API endpoint for stripe's server, the /v1/charge or whatever it is, yes anyone can see it but you pass along your specific stripe token for the card as well as your secret API key, and this is all sent over HTTPS so no one is hacking that information (most likely). Not sure if this helped, hope it did though!